# Featured imaged not showing wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress blog, I would like to select a featured image so that when url is shared on social network like facebook it has an image. but I do not want that image to show up on the page or the post of website.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't give us nearly enough detail. At a minimum, you should post a relevant sample of the code that you have. I encourage you to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for guidance on asking good questions on this site.

Comment: WordPress SEO by Yoast can do this

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the template responsible for post visualisation and add the OpenGraph meta tag.

Here's the documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup

The tag you need is "og:image":

`<meta property="og:image" content="<your image path>" />`

Answer (score 0):

It is not a big problem. There are lot of plugins from wordpress by which you can set featured image for any posts. 
Here is the link to the plugin

[Featured image plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-image/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to modify the single.php file and page.php file.
You can remove the code segment that show featured image from the above two files.

also there are some plugin may do this functionality,
you can check this, But I haven't check this one.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-featured-image/